# Kernel 4.8 USB seems to be broken?

Tags: linux, usb

This happened back in the 4.8 release candidate and I thought it would be fixed when the kernel went stable but I'm still having the issue. The kernel seems to randomly reset my USB controller or do something to that effect. Basically all my USB devices stop will randomly stop working and I have to force reboot the system to get them to come back only to have them work for 5 minutes or so before doing it again. I've rolled back to 4.7.6 so I can use my system but 4.8 just doesn't seem to want to work with USB. This is what I found in syslog and I think it's a log of the issue.

```
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop kernel: [  143.307247] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: HcDoneHead not written back; disabled
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop kernel: [  143.307251] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: HC died; cleaning up
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop kernel: [  143.307292] usb 10-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech G700s Rechargeable Gaming Mouse
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) evdev: Logitech G700s Rechargeable Gaming Mouse: Close
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 4
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech G700s Rechargeable Gaming Mouse
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop pulseaudio[804]: Got POLLNVAL from ALSA
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop pulseaudio[804]: Could not recover from POLLERR|POLLNVAL|POLLHUP with snd_pcm_prepare(): No such device
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop kernel: [  143.427525] usb 10-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gnome-session[720]: (gnome-settings-daemon:778): media-keys-plugin-WARNING **: Unable to get default sink
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) evdev: Logitech G700s Rechargeable Gaming Mouse: Close
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 15
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Logitech G933 Gaming Wireless Headset
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop kernel: [  143.483518] usb 10-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) evdev: Logitech Logitech G933 Gaming Wireless Headset: Close
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech USB Receiver
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Close
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 21
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech USB Receiver
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop kernel: [  143.623574] usb 10-5: USB disconnect, device number 5
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Close
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 22
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Gaming Keyboard G910
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) evdev: Logitech Gaming Keyboard G910: Close
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 23
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Gaming Keyboard G910
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) evdev: Logitech Gaming Keyboard G910: Close
Oct  2 22:23:31 user-desktop gdm-Xorg-:0[701]: (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
```

Comment: Try to find the list of dependencies to see if you need something new (udev for instance), otherwise file a bug with them, not with us.

Comment: Has been working fine for me for the last couple of days...